# Convert "," to ";" in a CSV file Google script

Tags: export-to-csv

With the below code my goal is to extract a sheet from the Google sheet file in `CSV` format. However, when I want to convert the `,` to `;` the following error message appears:

> r.join is not a function

Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Also, do you think it is possible to download this new file directly to the desktop of the computer ?

```
function sheetToCsv(){
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheet_Name = "Int_Module";
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_Name)
  var sheetNameId = sheet.getSheetId().toString();
  
  params= ssID+"/export?gid="+sheetNameId +"&format=csv"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ params
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);  
  var newfile = [result].map(r => r.join(";")).join("\n");
  newfile.createFile(fileName, outputData, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Do you mind clarifying, why you're trying to change the delimiter for CSV file from `,` to `;`? Also, I'm not exactly following what you're trying to do? What language/frameworks are you using?

Comment: Hello,

I use the Google script language. The purpose of this macro is to extract a sheet from a google sheet file and download it directly to the desktop of the local computer. I would also like this CSV file to contain semicolons as separator and not commas. When I run the macro, the following error message appears: ""r.join is not a function" and I have no idea how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that there is 2 questions ... how to produce CSV file with semi-colon, and how to download the file directly to your PC.

1- To produce the csv content, try

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var sep = ';'
  const content = sh.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((s, r) => s += r.map(c => c + sep).join("") + '\n', "")
```

2- To download, you will have to go through an html page.

Try this for both needs

```
function downloadMyCSVFile() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var sep = ';'
  const content = sh.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((s, r) => s += r.map(c => c + sep).join("") + '\n', "")
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`
<html><body onload="document.getElementById('dwn-btn').click()">
<textarea id="text-val" rows="10" style="display:none;">${content}</textarea>
<input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Download text file" style="display:none;"/>
<script>
window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},100)}
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
    var filename = "${sh.getName()}.csv";
    download(filename, text);
  close();
}, false);
</script>
</body></html>  
  `)
    .setWidth(250).setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Downloading ...");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your code looks much simpler than mine. Do you think it is possible to isolate a single sheet from the file using your first line of code because the active sheet is not necessarily the one I want to download. 

When I run your code, it gives me an error on the last line with the following message: 
"Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context."
Would you know how to solve it, excuse me I don't have deep knowledge in coding I try to manage with my means

Comment: if you want to perform on a specific sheet, try with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('here the name of sheet')`

Comment: the error is due that you have launched the code when you were in the script editor. Add a button or a custom menu and launch it from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hello, everything works perfectly, thank you for your help!